# Is there any way to Get data by PHP code insted of HTML from

Tags: php

I'm newbie in PHP.I want to know that,I taking data by html form and a .php file.
like:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="show.php">
<strong>Please Enter the Unique id</strong><br/><br/>
Unique id:
<!-- name of this text field is "tel" -->
<input name="id" type="text" id="id" />
<p>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
</p>
</form>
</html>
```

---

Then,I used show.php file to get the 'id'.like:

```
$id=$_POST['id'];
```

---

Is there any way to take input by php code???
Update:

In "C" we take ant input by this way

```
scanf("%d",a);
```

is there any way to do so in PHP.I think now all you may be clear what I'm trying to say??

Thanks
Yasir Adnan.

Comment: What do you mean by *"take input by php code"*?

Comment: $id=$_POST['id'];
**is 'php code'**. I think you need to explain what you want a bit better so people here can answer your question.

Comment: You are taking input using PHP, but you have to take it *from* somewhere. That somewhere is usually a form.

Answer (score 1):

What you are you trying to get is wrong!

HTML:- It is the communicator between the user and the browser. It displays the contents according to the user input or html code.It gets data from user or from html code.

Php :- It is the communicator between server and the browser. It has the capability of collecting from some where else other than the code like mysql data base and then uses html to display the content!

Here you are asking php to do html work which is not correct!!

Answer (score 0):

the html

```
<input name="sb_id" type="text" id="sb_id" />
```

php

```
$id=$_POST['sb_id'];
```

Comment: Yes,that was a mistake.But,is there any way to take input by php code??

Comment: what do you mean by " to take input by php code" please explain

Comment: My answer, and all other answers in here, exactly do that. This is the way you take input from the user in php

Answer (score 0):

`$id = $_POST["sb_id"];` ?

Remember that $_POST["field_name"] where field_name must be match the `name` attribute of your `<input />` tag.

the `id` attribute of input tag is not sent to server inside the $_POST array. It`s typically  used in client-side.

Comment: PHP is server side, not client side, so -1.

Comment: I never said PHP was client-side. The id is only used in client-side. You`re flagged.

Comment: He's using name="id", so `id` is perfectly passing to the server. Don't know where you took `sb_id` though.

Comment: @vascowhite "It" was referring to the id of an element, which is typically used on client-side. (Unless using DOMDocument)

Comment: I just said that: Id attribute of input tag is not sent to $_POST. Just the name attribute. You are messing the things.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you do take the input by your php code. Your variable `$id` took the value of `$_POST['id']` which contains the input of the textfield.

After this step you can work with the variable like any other

Answer (score 0):

You can get data in your PHP code through GET and POST parameters. Those parameters are part of the HTTP request.

The GET parameters are in the url :

```
http://mywebsite.com/id=3&name=test
```

Then you get them using:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$name = $_GET['name'];
```

So you can get input data through this way when people visit the URL, call it in AJAX, or call the URL in another application (like a webservice). But no matter how it's called, it's the same for you on the PHP side.

The POST parameters are in the HTTP request, you can't pass them through the URL. You can do that by using an HTML form, or by creating the HTTP request yourself. If you are using Javascript to call your PHP code (and pass data to it), you can use AJAX to do that for example. You, in your PHP code, can get the variables this way:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want console-style I/O, you should probably check JavaScript/AJAX. The second one will allow you to write your own wrapper that will help you to process the input by your server "on air".
The problem is, you still need to use $_POST for AJAX. And, which is more important, it's easier (and cheaper for the server) to validate and process input by JS (and to validate and process it further on the server-side after submit).

And if the question is "how can I get the variable from the needed format?", the answer is: try using regexps/parsing the string.

Oh, btw: there IS scanf() in php, and it's called 'sscanf' ('fscanf' for files).